# Sybase =* joing to mysql right outer join

Tags: mysql, sybase, outer-join

I have the the following Sybase sql statement that contains a right outer join (i think) using the syntax =* . I am trying to replicate this in mysql and failing horribly. Can anyone suggest how i state the right outer join in the from section.

```
SELECT database1.inst.regionAbb,
       database1.inst.regionalCode,
       database1.inst.instCode,
       database1.inst.name,
       database1.inst.yCode,
       database1.blac.customerCode,
       database1.inst.transportCode,
       database1.inst.Agreement,
       database1.addr.telephone,
       database1.addr.fax,
       database1.addr.email,
       database1.addr.id contactaddr,
       database1.inst.nameAbb,
       database1.inst.messageType,
       database1.inst.closedFrom,
       database1.inst.closedTo,
       database1.inst.costScheme1,
       database1.inst.costScheme2,
       database1.inst.costScheme3,
       database1.inst.costScheme4,
       database1.inst.costScheme5,
       now() updated

FROM database1.Table1 inst,
     database1.Table2 addr,
     database1.Table3 blac

WHERE ((database1.addr.instCode = database1.inst.instCode) **
       AND ((database1.blac.instCode =* database1.inst.instCode)**
       AND (database1.blac.preferred = "Y")))
       AND ((database1.addr.id = database1.inst.Address
       AND database1.inst.lendingTable2 != 0)
       OR (database1.addr.id = database1.inst.mainTable2
       AND database1.inst.lendingTable2 = 0))
```

Comment: what's up with the "orginal Sybase query." in the middle?

Comment: Sorry OGHaza the post got jumbled up. I have corrected the SQL. Can you help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sybase I'm afraid, but are you trying to go from sysbase -> mysql or mysql -> sysbase, because I might be able to advise if you're trying to go to mysql

Comment: Trying to go from sybase to mysql.  It is the part in the where clause  "=*" which represents (i believe) a right outer join but in mysql you specify the joins in the from section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sybase, but I think this is what you're going for:

```
SELECT * FROM 
FROM database1.Table1 inst,
INNER JOIN database1.Table2 addr ON addr.instCode = inst.instCode
LEFT JOIN database1.Table3 blac ON blac.instCode = inst.instCode
WHERE blac.preferred = "Y"
  OR (blac.preferred IS NULL AND
       ((addr.id = inst.Address    AND inst.lendingTable2 != 0)
     OR (addr.id = inst.mainTable2 AND inst.lendingTable2 = 0)))
```

This assumes it only does the final check if there is no `blac` record - if you actually want to do that check if there is no `blac` record OR `blac.preferred != 'Y'` then you can remove the `blac.preferred IS NULL AND` as well as the extra pair of parenthesis.

Comment: Not quite right. It gives me too few a result i think because the right outer is not in there. If i change the the line "INNER JOIN database1.Table3 blac ON blac.instCode = inst.instCode" to Right outer Join it does not work either. hurrumph. Definitely making progress though

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reread the question text when I came back to answer this today - but from looking at the where clause it seemed to me INNER JOINS were what you needed. You specify `blac.preferred = "Y"` and that `addr.id = inst.Address OR inst.mainTable2`. So to fulfil those WHERE requirements all 3 tables would need a corresponding record to appear in the result set - I suspect the WHERE clause is incorrect compared to your one in Sybase (or that Sybase treats JOINS differently)

Comment: Is it the case that you always want to return an `inst` record even if `boac` or `addr` records don't exist?

Comment: I believe it is bring a record back even if blac record does not exist. It needs to have an inst record and a addr record but not specifically a blac record.  The next section containing the OR then caters if there is not blac account.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer, let me know if that's what you want

Comment: still not quite right. There are 3 joins in the original query. I think we are missing                                                    AND ((database1.addr.id = database1.inst.Address

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM 
((database1.Table1 inst 
left join database1.Table3 blac on inst.instCode=blac.instCode and blac.preferred="Y")
join database1.Table2 addr on (addr.instCode=inst.instCode and ((addr.id = inst.lendingTable2 and inst.lendingTable2<>0) 
or ((addr.id=inst.mainTable2 ) and ( inst.lendingTable2=0)))));